# select data from db to find datediff in condition

Tags: php, mysql

Сan anybody help me, guys? I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id_instansi, nama_file, valid_date,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, valid_date, CURDATE()) AS selisih
FROM tbl_attachment
```

[image]

My problem is that I just want to show the rows which have '*selisih*' value = -4, not all. 
Can anybody tell me how to write a right query to solve my problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT id_instansi, nama_file, valid_date, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, valid_date, CURDATE()) AS selisih FROM tbl_attachment 
**WHERE** TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, valid_date, CURDATE())=-4
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. Code-only answers are considered low quality.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id_instansi, nama_file, valid_date,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, valid_date, CURDATE()) AS selisih
FROM tbl_attachment
WHERE
    selisih = -4
```